# how to change WordPress URL on all pages?

Tags: php, wordpress

how to change WordPress URL on all pages? suppose we have a xyz.com. Now I want something like xyz.com/test when customer visiting to xyz.com. and for all newly created pages must be something like xyz.com/test/Newpage.

Comment: use url rewrite to rewrite you urls

Comment: search online, do some research, then ask

Comment: I do research but didn't find anything because I don't have knowledge of PHP.

Comment: Check this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/

Comment: If you don't have any knowledge of PHP, doesn't show any research effort and you're expecting an answer from us, maybe StackOverflow isn't the right place for this question. See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I added the plugins it works for all the pages and post but I want to change main site URL for example when going to xyz.com it must be changed to xyz.com/test

Answer (score 1):

For example, if your new directory is called application, you would visit www.your-site.com/application/wp-admin or www.your-site.com/application/wp-login.php.

Update /wp-blog-header.php to include your new directory. For example, if your new folder is called application, you would change the file path to this: /application/wp-blog-header.php.

Change this line in the index.php int the root folder.

```
/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the Wordpress URL for all pages then you can follow below step,

1. Login to WordPress
2. Open the existing page or create a new page
3. Enter a Title if necessary
4. Save the page, this will automatically create a URL
5. Look directly under the title field, you will see Permalink: followed    by the URL
6. Click the Edit button behind the link
7. Type in the new URL and click OK
8. Save the page or post

Comment: how to manage the link in your page. give me screenshot? so , I will help you

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Customize Permalink Structure, You can choose "Post name" option.

Post name - An example of the post name structure is http://www.sample.com/sample-post

Hope this will helps you.